# How to delay code execution?

Tags: php, redirect

How can I delay the execution of a block of code in php?

```
    if ($qry->execute($leads)) {
    echo'<div class="note success">' . 
            $_POST["first_name"] . ', Your entry was successful!
        </div>';

        // Set up email params
```

This code displays a "Successful" message then emails the users. After displaying the the message, I want to redirect the user.

Is this possible in PHP? Do I need to use JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Delay it to when or how long?

Comment: PHP runs before the webpage is presented to the user. So, unless you want to present them a blank page for 10 seconds (which I doubt), you're going to have to use Javascript/Headers, yes.

Comment: I just noticed you're using `$_POST['first_name']` directly, without passing it through [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). This may open up your site to [cross-site-scripting attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29); consider sanitizing user-submitted data to prevent this security vulnerability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to delay the execution of PHP code, you can use the [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function. However, it appears that you want to delay a redirect for the client. You can do this with JavaScript, `<meta>` refresh and the `Refresh` header.

Using the `Refresh` header:

```
header('Refresh: «timeout in seconds»; URL=http://example.com/myurl');
```

Using `<meta>` refresh:

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="«timeout in seconds»; URL=http://example.com/myurl">
```

Using JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 location.replace("/myurl");
},«timeout in milliseconds»);
```

The best is to use a combination of these three, and also show a message for users that have disabled these redirection technologies with a link that allows them to click through manually.

Answer (score 3):

Since output has already occurred, you cannot do an HTTP Header redirection. Instead, you should set up a meta-refresh to redirect the user in the `<head>` of your HTML document:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://www.example.com/newpage.php" />
```

Comment: The form is positing to itself. What's another way to do a redirect in js withing the `<body>`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side language, which is executed before anything is shown to the user.

This is something that would have to take place after the page is rendered, so yes Javascript would be a better solution.